# how to adjust a cloth model to fit a body model

Tags: mesh, sculpt

I found a good cloth model file from some website.
I want to put/wear this cloth model to my human model.
Do need advise/tutorial video for what kind of skill for this purpose, sculpt a little is ok, but if more, the cloth will be not look good. Also tried shrink modifier, help a little but not idea.
The tutorials I find are all about how to quickly make cloth for a body, not suit the purpose.

Comment: Hello, there are several ways to make clothes, maybe take a look at some tutorials like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h89tkUJLuM or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and show what you don't like? Scaling and sculpting should do the trick. But when the cloth is textured and has a normal map and the size differs a lot then there can be stretching and bad deformations.